# ReactJS: What is the idiomatic way to fetch and update data through a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm trying to wrap my head around the best way to update data through an HTML form. Take the example from the ReactJS webpage:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Say you wanted to implement the ability for a user to edit a comment that she had posted in the past (i.e. not in the current session and so must be fetched from the server). The edit comment page would need to prefill the comment's existing author name and text. How would you implement fetching the comment data and pre-filling the comment form? Here are the conflicting ideas I have in my head that I can't sort out (let's call the new component `CommentEdit`):

- The initial comment author and text should be props of `CommentEdit` since they are not state
- The `CommentEdit` component should be reusable so it should be able to fetch the initial data from the server itself, but then it has to be saved as state
- If the parent of `CommentEdit` were to fetch and set the props for `CommentEdit`, it would have to save it as state, so there aren't much savings there
- Something like Flux might work, but Flux confuses me even more. If Flux were to store comments, would it have to save every comment for the user? What would happen if the user had thousands of comments?

Honestly, I just wish components could change their own props. Seems like it would make components a lot more reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by adding a "wrapper" parent to each of my components. The wrapper component is responsible for fetching data from the server, which it will store in its state. The wrapper will pass the fetched state as props to its children. I then abstracted this setup as mixins, creating a wrapper mixin and wrapper child mixin so that I can re-use this setup easily.

This pattern works really well for typical forms in your app. The wrapper will fetch data to pre-populate the form and the child will send the form to the server and will be responsible for error-handling.

Here's an example:

```
// This handles the form submission and error handling
var EditFormMixin = {
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {formState:FORM_STATE_EDITING, errors:{}}
  },
  handleSubmitBase: function(event, url, data, method, success, error) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({formState:FORM_STATE_SUBMITTING, errors:{}});
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        method: method,
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({formState:FORM_STATE_SUBMITTED});
            if (success) {
                success();
            };
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            this.setState({formState:FORM_STATE_EDITING});
            if (xhr.status == 400) {
                this.setState({errors:xhr.responseJSON});
            }
            if (error) {
                error();
            }
        }.bind(this)
    });
  }
};

// This handles fetching the initial data for the form
var EditFormWrapperMixin = {
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: {}, loadState:LOAD_STATE_UNLOADED, url:this.getUrl()};
  },
  fetch: function() {
    this.setState({loadState:LOAD_STATE_LOADING})
    $.ajax({
        url: this.state.url,
        dataType: "json",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({data:data, loadState:LOAD_STATE_LOADED});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        }.bind(this)
    });
  }
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.fetch();
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    var url = this.getUrl();
    this.setState({url:url}, function() {
        this.fetch();
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Honestly, I just wish components could change their own props. Seems like it would make components a lot more reusable.

Not really, components that can change their own props are not more reusable then ones that cannot, just that their under the hood implementation will get much more complicated.

The current `react.js` flow with data going down and events bubbling up makes component "very" deterministic as at any time in the component lifecycle you know what outputs will the component generate based on the inputs you give to it. This helps a lot also when debugging and unit test the app.

Now, to your dilemma, `CommentEdit` needs only have a `content` property, as the author will not change and will always be the one logged into the website. Other state is not necessary as the edited content will be bubbled up when the user clicks on the `save` button, and will be inserted into the list when the `comments` list stored in the `state` of one of the component ancestors will be updated.

If you properly set the `key` property for each comment, then react will nicely notice that the html element of the edited comment doesn't need to be re-created, only the `innerHTML` of the html element that renders the comment will need to change.

You can add the author as a prop if you want it displayed, it will not affect/improve the component itself unless you want to build multiple sites with this layout.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although in this case ```content``` is the only property, what if the component had many properties? Won't that require the parent component to maintain all of the properties in its state?

Comment: Depending of the data model and UI the properties of children components might need to be retrieved from state or can be inferred from own properties. Still it a much cleaner design as data flows in one direction only, which makes you application architecture more robust.

Answer (score -2):

Flux is the best tool you can use to fetch data out of the app, you don't have to use states inside the components, use props to charge the initial data, then use react.DOMNode to get data from every element of the form you need https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.finddomnode , also use refs inside all the form components, finally you can use flux to send your data to a server and save it.